# Sorting method in d3js not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b) bar chart you can sort by clicking the "sort values" checkbox, it works initialy, but if you try to uncheck the box again it stops working.

I get no errors from this either, I suspect that it has something to do with `data` not being loaded properly or some part of my code is structured poorly.

Here's a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iKNgC22rPYefisMkHTiE?p=preview)

Comment: You always provide a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/) which makes it easier to edit. Can you do that here as well? :)

Comment: Added a plunker! @Shashank

Comment: Thanks. I'll update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the **unchecking of the sort values** to NOT work was the `sortIndex`.

As the data was being sorted, the original data itself was manipulated and the new `sortIndex` was based on this new data which resulted in the same array as the sorted one.

What I did is added an `init()` function to initialize the `data` and `sortIndex` for the very first time. Also, on *every data update*, change the `sortIndex` based on the *original* data and **NOT** in the `update` function.

Relevant code:

```
d3.select("#year").on('change', function() {
  data = d3.select('#year').property('value') == '2017' ? data1 : data2;
  sortIndex = data.map( function(d) { return d.month} );
  update();
});
```

Here's an updated Plunkr with the changes:

[Plunkr with sort values onChange fixed](https://plnkr.co/edit/NtI1FKTG88xyp7loaTN8?p=preview)

Hope this helps. :)