# Sorting function issue with grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is similar to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344419/sorting-method-in-d3js-not-working), the difference is that the answer to that question doesn't work for my new chart.

Code here: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UK21mpcKsc4bkbtHeAzX?p=preview)

The issue is that the sorting toggle checkbox stops sorting the chart when you try to uncheck the box again.

If I remove the function from `d3.select("#myCheckbox")` and replace it with `d3.select("#myCheckbox").on('change', update)` it works again, but rather than the bars shifting x position it only shifts the ticks position on the x-axis & the bars update and change position simultaniously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're reassigning `sortIndex` when clicking on the checkbox:

```
d3.select("#myCheckbox").on('change', function() {
    sortIndex = data.map( function(d) { return d.State} );
    update();
});
```

However, the very `data` it uses has been sorted!

The solution is simple, just remove that:

```
d3.select("#myCheckbox").on('change', update);
```

Besides that, make sure you're using the proper key function:

```
var barGroups = g.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(data, function(d){return d.State});
```

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/goU5K7LB4Gj1jhynLqGt?p=preview

Comment: @RobertAndersson I thought you were using a key function, I told you to use them yesterday! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433721/5768908 Now I hope you see how important they are!

Comment: I didn't think that you needed it if you assigned another `.data` to the same selection. I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: @RobertAndersson yes, but the issue is that `data` assigns the data in a *first-come-first-served* basis, look what the documentation says: *"If a key function is not specified, then the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on"*.